# Modificate in live value of a input

Tags: javascript

I have a form conversion, and I need the result is updated according to the amount entered by the user **in live**.

But the result is always the same.
I think the problem is in the variable price, this is not updated with the last written number of input.

This is the form

```
<input type="text" id="from_amount" value="0" name="amount" /> 
<span class="num" id="conv_result">0</span>
<input type="submit" action="" method="" >
```

This is the  javascript

```
function a(){

var price = $("#from_amount").val(); //Get the number of the input

if (price == 0){
        var total = 1;
    }else if (price > 20 && price < 30){
        var total = price * 2;
    }else{ 
        var total = 4;
}
     return total;
}

  var conver = {
     'people': {
     'rooms': a() 
      },
  };
```

Comment: Can you show a more complete example? In your source, `a()` is never called. I could guess that it gets called on a click of the button, and then the submit action of the button messes things up, but that would be just a guess.

Comment: I call the function a() in the var conver = rooms. 
In another part of the code handling this result and show it in id = "conv_result".
But what I need is to get the number entered in the input id = "from_amount".
I've tried with .on (change
But I have not succeeded.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/jw9woavd/
What is not working?